# ogr2ogr merge fgdb (while importing to PostGIS)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, merge, ogr2ogr, append

I have millions of records and hundreds of tables in several file geodatabases..

The tables name in these FGDBs are all same but just in different areas.

For instance, the Admin table, you see below, is California data (but the FGDB named as file.gdb), and there is another Admin table in New York (also the FGDB named as file.gdb) data

[image]

To have better access and use st_* functions, I was importing the FGDBs to my PostgreSQL one by one. (ultimately I am going to write a `bash` script to automate this)

As far as I know, once the tables are imported to PostgreSQL I can append tables using `-update -append` options.

So, this is my command below

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -progress -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5433 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres" file.gdb -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=shape -t_srs EPSG:3857
```

but this gives me this error message

> Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is
>          being appended to.
>   ERROR 1: ?ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
>   ?ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 1 from layer Admin.
>   ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
>   translation of layer Admin (use -skipfailures to skip errors)

Using -skipfailures seems to be dangerous because it might skip some of my data.

Will there be another solution to breakthrough this issue?

Comment: Please use the code formatter (`{}`) to make your code legible (backtics are just for individual words within a paragraph). Note that PostGIS is not a database, just the spatial extension to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @vince thanks for your comment. I am still new to the stackoverflow editing tool. I will read more carefully about the manual

Comment: The error may come from some other place. If your GDAL build supports debugging you may see something interesting by adding `--debug on` into your command. As a blind guess I suggest to add `-unsetFid` to the command.

Comment: @user30184 I added --debug and the error says (```ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'file.gdb'!```)

Comment: Is is a violation of good security practice to load any user data as the `postgres` user or to the `postgres` database. Instead you should create login users and at least one user database (with `postgis` enabled). Please pick up a book on PostgreSQL before you accidentally damage your database and destroy all your effort to date.

Comment: @Vince the account is for the test purpose. I will eventually change to my own id/pw of course :)

Comment: @user30184 it seems like ```--debug``` should be right after the ogr2ogr. It still gives me a same error message (> ERROR 1: ?ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.)

Comment: merging them into one FGDB doesn't seem to be an issue. works fine. but merging them while importing to postgresql is the issue.

Comment: I tend to place `--debug on` (notise "on") last in the command so it is easy to remove when not needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "I'll do it right later" approach destroys the current database, as much as logging in as Administrator on a Windows box and using C:\Windows as your temporary folder as you create thousands of files with random 8-character names and a .exe suffix. It's possible that your current issue is a name conflict that wouldn't exist if you used best practice.

Comment: @Vince, ouch. Very true, though.

Comment: @Vince, I will try now and share the results soon

Comment: @vince, yes, you are right. as soon as i changed the DB and user/pw. It does work like a magic. thanks for the comment